# Drive encryption without update problems

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption

I want to encrypt my hard drive or at least my user folder. Until now, I did this using the verycrypt drive encryption. The problem is, windows is unable to do bigger updates (like the April update) if veracrypt is enabled.

Is it possible to do a fast & secure drive/user encryption without any update problems? I would actually prefer a user folder encryption, because it will cause no update problems for sure, but I don't know any program (or windows feature) which can do this. Is it possible?

My OS is windows 10 pro (april update) on a samsung ssd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer supports it, using [BitLocker](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2308725/encryption/a-beginners-guide-to-bitlocker-windows-built-in-encryption-tool.html) is the best solution.

Comment: Is bitlocker encryption for sure compatible with windows updates? And is it really secure? Microsoft isn't really a trustworthy company.

Comment: Yes. Since BitLocker is native, there won't be any issues. If you're concerned about nation-state level hostile actors, there may be better solutions, but by and large, BitLocker is plenty secure.